# How to switch Google (and Wikipedia) search box suggestion with radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search-engine, wiki-engine

I added Google and Wikipedia search box to a page and I'm looking for a way to change the suggestions depending on the selected radio button.

In fact the suggestions language should change depending on the language checked.

Here is my actual code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Google Suggest Test</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="googlesuggest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" id="google_suggest" >
 <div>
  <input name="q" value="" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
  <input type="hidden" name="complete" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
  <input type="hidden" name="oe" value="UTF-8" />
  <input type="hidden" name="num" value="30" />
  <input type="hidden" name="channel" value="s" />
  <br />
  <label for="all"><input id="all" type="radio" name="lr" value="" checked="checked" />All</label>
  <label for="lang_en"><input id="lang_en" type="radio" name="lr" value="lang_en" />English</label>
  <label for="lang_fr"><input id="lang_fr" type="radio" name="lr" value="lang_fr" />French</label>
  <label for="lang_de"><input id="lang_de" type="radio" name="lr" value="lang_de" />German</label>
  <label for="lang_ru"><input id="lang_ru" type="radio" name="lr" value="lang_ru" />Russian</label> 
  <label for="lang_es"><input id="lang_es" type="radio" name="lr" value="lang_es" />Spanish</label>
  <br /><br />
 </div>
</form>
<form method="post" action="wikipedia_action.php">
 <div>
  <input type="text" name="wikipedia_field" />
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
  <br />
  <label for="wik_en"><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="wikipedia" id="wik_en" value="wik_en" />English</label>
  <label for="wik_fr"><input type="radio" name="wikipedia" id="wik_fr" value="wik_fr" />French</label>
  <label for="wik_de"><input type="radio" name="wikipedia" id="wik_de" value="wik_de" />German</label>
  <label for="wik_ru"><input type="radio" name="wikipedia" id="wik_ru" value="wik_ru" />Russian</label>
  <label for="wik_es"><input type="radio" name="wikipedia" id="wik_es" value="wik_es" />Spanish</label>
 </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Script googlesuggest.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

window.google = {
    kEI: "wR-4SfmNIMyA-AbluKj5Cg",
    kEXPI: "17259,17291,18169",
    kHL: "fr"
};
var _gjwl = location;
function _gjuc() {
    var a = _gjwl.hash.substring(1);
    if (/(^|&)q=/.test(a) && a.indexOf("#") == -1 && !/(^|&)cad=h($|&)/.test(a)) {
        _gjwl.replace("search?" + a.replace(/(^|&)fp=[^&]*/g, "") + "&cad=h");
        return 1
    }
    return 0
};
window._gjuc && location.hash && _gjuc();

google.y = {};
google.x = function(e, g) {
    google.y[e.id] = [e, g];
    return false
};
window.clk = function(b, c, d, e, f, g, h) {
    if (document.images) {
        var a = encodeURIComponent || escape;
        (new Image).src = ["/url?sa=T", c ? "&oi=" + a(c) : "", d ? "&cad=" + a(d) : "", "&ct=", a(e), "&cd=", a(f), b ? "&url=" + a(b.replace(/#.*/, "")).replace(/\+/g, "%2B") : "", "&ei=wR-4SfmNIMyA-AbluKj5Cg", g].join("")
    }
    return true
};
window.gbar = {
    qs: function() {},
    tg: function(e) {
        var o = {
            id: 'gbar'
        };
        for (i in e) o[i] = e[i];
        google.x(o,
        function() {
            gbar.tg(o)
        })
    }
};

if (google.y) google.y.first = [];
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var xjs = document.createElement('script');
    xjs.src = 'http://www.google.com/extern_js/f/CgJmciswCjgNLCswDjgELCswFjgELCswFzgBLCswGDgDLCswJTjJiAEsKzAnOAAs/4Pb8ykSjyRQ.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(xjs)
},
0);
google.y.first.push(
    function(){
        var google_suggest = document.getElementById('google_suggest');
        google.ac.i(
            google_suggest,
            google_suggest.q,
            '',
            ''
        )
    }
)
function _gjp() { ! (location.hash && _gjuc()) && setTimeout(_gjp, 500);
}
window._gjuc && _gjp();

});
```

PHP of wikipedia_action.php

```
<?php
$search_field = trim($_POST['wikipedia_field']);
$search_engine = trim($_POST['wikipedia']);
$url_params = preg_replace('/(\ )+/', '+', $search_field);
$url = array('wik_en'=>'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=', 'wik_fr'=>'http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=', 'wik_de'=>'http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=', 'wik_ru'=>'http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=', 'wik_es'=>'http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=');
header('Location:'.$url[$_POST['wikipedia']].$url_params)
?>
```

Actually I have 2 problems…

1 - I noticed for Google suggestions that changing **kHL:"en"** into **kHL:"fr"** for French or **kHL:"de"** for German does the trick but I don't know how to change it depending on radio button checked?
(and without some onClick, jQuery should be better)

2 - I also failed to set up Wikipedia suggestion system that's why I'm looking for this (and suggestions change) too.
It's used here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%A9cial:Recherche

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spezial:Suche

Etc.

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the two scripts working independently? In other words, one page with Google suggest and one with WP suggest? If so, I would recommend simply using two forms, with unique IDs, allowing each one to work separately.

Hide the one you're not using. When you click the radio button to switch 'em, hide one form and display the other.

Comment: I have 1 form for Google and an other for Wikipedia but both on the same page. But for each form I would like to change script depending on language selected.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question and though the radio button was to switch between Google or Wikipedia. Disregard.

Answer (score 0):

This post should really be broken down into 2 separate questions. As far as the Google Suggest part of your question. You can the following bit of jquery code to change the kHL when clicking on the radio button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#google_suggest input[type='radio']").click(function(){
            alert("kHL Before="+window.google.kHL);
            window.google.kHL = this.id.replace('lang_','');    
            alert("kHL After="+window.google.kHL);
        });   
    });
 </script>
```

However, while you can tell by the alerts that the kHL changes correctly, the GoogleSuggest dropdown does not change the language. In other words, the kHL is stuck to what was setup inside `$(document).ready()`.

The only thing that I can think of is reloading the googlesuggest.js dynamically with the `onchange()` event. This is something you will need to investigate further.

Comment: You're right I'll seperate this post in 2, or edit it once I'll find out about Wikipedia system and remove my question about it.
I'll look into it, try your code and suggestions and let you know.